# Measure height of a element in semantic react ui

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to measure the height of a component, If i try to get the ref and find the offsetHeight, the ref is returned to be null always. so How to measure the height for a react-semantic-ui component.

```
<Container ref={rf=>this.container=rf} style={{overflowY:"auto"}}>
    <Item.Group divided >
        <ItemList items={items}></ItemList>
    </Item.Group>
</Container>
```

here **this.container** is always **null**

What other ways are there to measure the height of a react-semantic-ui component ?

Comment: are you measuring height in the ```componentDidMount()``` hook?

Comment: yeah, i am measuring only after the mounting. but the ref is not set. its always null

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.container.offsetHeight` in `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` methods.

It is possible to wrap your components into `<div ref={...}></div>`. Then you can get height of the `div`. If your higher component doesn't have margins, height of div and your component will be the same.

Note:

1. When the ref attribute is used on a custom component declared as a class, the ref callback receives the mounted instance of the component as its argument.
2. When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback receives the underlying DOM element as its argument.
3. You **may not** use the ref attribute on functional components because they don’t have instances

Returned values from 1 and 2 have different properties and methods. There is a doc https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: i am accessing this.container.offsetHeight after component mounted, but the ref is still not set. this.container is null inside componentDidMount

Comment: @StarLord Try to use ref for <div/> component. Because there are some differences https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @StarLord 1. When the ref attribute is used on a custom component declared as a class, the ref callback receives the mounted instance of the component as its argument.
2. When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback receives the underlying DOM element as its argument.

Comment: 3. You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don’t have instances

Answer (score 0):

@bogdan-surai, can you test the following code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const container = this.container;
    if (!container) {
      return;
    }
    const specs = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(specs);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@salman.zare  Yep. It doesn't work when `componentDidMount` just have fired. I guess the cause is height really equals 0 at that moment. But we can run `setInterval` to get height in few time later.

This code works for me

```
  componentDidMount() {

        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {

           const container = this.container;
           if (!container) {
              return;
           }
           const specs = container.getBoundingClientRect();
           console.log(specs);
           console.log(this.scrollComponent.offsetHeight);

           this.setState(() => ({ height: specs.height }));
        }, 100);


    }
```

Then I see it in the browser's console.

```
DOMRect {x: 0, y: 120, width: 693, height: 0, top: 120, …}
DOMRect {x: 0, y: 16, width: 678, height: 4068, top: 16, …}
```